# how to draw outlines of objects on an image to a separate image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

i am working on a puzzle, my final task here is to identify edge type of the puzzle piece.

[image]

as shown in the above image i have mange to rotate and crop out every edge of the piece in same angle. my next step is to separate the edge line into a separate image like as shown in the image bellow

[image]

then to fill up one side of the line with with a color and try to process it to decide what type of edge it is.

i dont see a proper way to separate the edge line from the image for now.

my approach:: 
one way to do is scan pixel by pixel and find the black pixels where there is a nun black pixel next to it. this is a code that i can implement. but it feels like a primitive and a time consuming approach.

so if there you can offer any help or ideas, or any completely different way to detect the hollows and humps.

thanks in advance..

Comment: I would suggest opencv to find contours. google around and you'll find tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert your color image to grayscale. Then apply a threshold, say zero to obtain a binary image. You may have to use morphological operations to further process the binary image if there are holes. Then find the contours of this image and draw them to a new image.

[image: rgb]

[image: binary]

[image: cont]

A simple code is given below, using `opencv 4.0.1` in `python 2.7`.

```
bgr = cv2.imread('puzzle.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, roi = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('/home/dhanushka/stack/roi.png', roi)
cont = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
output = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(output, cont[0], -1, (255, 255, 255))

# removing boundary
boundary = 255*np.ones(gray.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
boundary[1:boundary.shape[0]-1, 1:boundary.shape[1]-1] = 0

toremove = output & boundary
output = output ^ toremove
```

Comment: i see, this is pretty close to what i want, but i only want the main edge in the final image. how can i separate that from this image... i also did a little more about it asked another question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069724/how-to-separate-two-parts-of-an-image-in-rgba-formate

Comment: can u take a look at both the questions and help me out a bit more.. thanks

Comment: and where is the drawContours function coming from

Comment: Those edges that you want to remove are along the boundary of the image, so you can draw this boundary in another image and perform an AND operation with the contour image, which gives you the edges that should be removed. Then perform an XOR. I'll try to provide and example if I get free time. `drawContours` is also in opencv. I edited the code.

Comment: @Eshaka I added boundary removing. Check if that's what you want.

Comment: let me try.. i am having trouble running this.. i think its the opencv version. let you know soon

Comment: not exactly, but i found a way to do what i want to do.. thanks. i got the color inverse of the image and then findContours, it give 2 contours. replace the -1 with the range(len(cont[1]) give separate outputs of the objects, then i can select.... Thank you so much